# What is the big deal if a belief's certainty is grounded by the subject's reasons for holding it?

Tags: epistemology

I was reading [this entry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/certainty/) on certainty. In 2.1, I came across this sentence:

> In general, every indubitability account of certainty will face a
> dilemma: when the subject finds herself incapable of doubting one of
> her beliefs, either she has good reasons for being incapable of
> doubting it, or she does not. If she does not have good reasons for
> being unable to doubt the belief, the type of certainty in question
> can be only psychological, not epistemic, in nature. On the other
> hand, if the subject does have good reasons for being unable to doubt
> the belief, the belief may be epistemically certain. **But, in this
> case, what grounds the certainty of the belief will be the subject’s
> reasons for holding it, and not the fact that the belief is
> indubitable.**

I think the last sentence is just hair-splitting. Okay, I understand that what really is grounding the certainty of the subject's belief is her reason(s) for holding that belief, not really due to the fact that the belief is indubitable because the subject wouldn't have held the (indubitable) belief if not for the reason(s). But who cares? What matters is that the belief be (rightfully) indubitable, not *how* the subject came to the conclusion of the belief's indubitability.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: How do we know that a belief is rightfully undubitable unless we have a good reason to think so? Being correct by accident like a stopped watch twice a day will do us little good, while having the proper foundations and methods to be correct most of the time will be much better. Properly sustained knowledge also has the benefit of being amendable, to take into account new facts, when pure psychological certainty is much more closed to revision. Most of the discussions turned into screaming match we witness are due to people being emotionally involved into their psychological certainties.

Comment: It is the other way around. It does not really matter whether a belief is certain/indubitable. What matters (philosophically) is that it is correct, or, at least, rationally justified. Psychological certainty is just icing on the cake that one can do without, it is of interest only insofar as it tracks justifiability.

Comment: Indeed if you treat all kinds of propositional attituding beliefs as justified true beliefs aka knowledge then my hair will be splitting too...